# command | grep | awk save into a variable or execute it as function

Tags: bash, grep, vim

I am trying to save the value of a command into a variable but it gives an error

```bsh
var = `cat $1 | grep "STAN: \[$2\]" | awk -F '|' '{print $3; exit}'`
```

It gives me the error

```
var: command not found
```

Comment: Welcome, in bash the variable assignment doesn't contain spaces: `var=foo`, not `var = foo`. Also is preferable to use `$()` for command substitution instead of backticks: `var=$(my command)`.

Comment: You can avoid the use of `cat`: `var=$(grep "STAN: \[$2\]" "$1" | awk -F '|' '{print $3; exit}')`

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that would give you an error, since the `=` in variable assignments can't be surrounded by whitespace in the shell. The shell would interpret the line as you wanting to run the command called `var` with the arguments `=` and whatever your command substitution returns (after additionally splitting the result into words and applying file name globbing to those words, since it's unquoted).

Instead, use

```bsh
var=$( awk -F '|' -v str="$2" '$0 ~ "STAN: \\[" str "\\]" { print $3; exit }' "$1" )
```

I also took the liberty to get rid of the `grep` and the `cat`, and to change the deprecated command substitution using backticks to one using `$( ... )` instead.

You could also do it with `grep`, `cut` and `head`:

```bsh
var=$( grep -e "STAN: \[$2\]" "$1" | head -n 1 | cut -d '|' -f 3 )
```

or, if your `grep` has the `-m` option to stop after a particular number of matches:

```bsh
var=$( grep -m 1 -e "STAN: \[$2\]" "$1" | cut -d '|' -f 3 )
```

or, if the expression that you're searching with is actually a string and not a regular expression:

```bsh
var=$( grep -m 1 -F -e "STAN: [$2]" "$1" | cut -d '|' -f 3 )
```

Comment: Another big benefit of the first, awk-based, solution in this answer is that the exit status of the $(...) is a better indication of whether or not everything worked.